# Defining the domain of an MGF?

Tags: normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

Let $Y=X^2$ and let $X$ follow a distribution of  $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ for $\sigma > 0$. Find the MGF of $Y$ and specify its domain.

So what I did was I did a change of variables:

$$P(Y<y)=P(X^2<y)$$
$$=P(-y^{1/2} < X < y^{1/2})$$ 
$$=P(X<y^{1/2}) - P(X<-y^{1/2})$$
$$=F_X(y^{1/2})-F_X(-y^{1/2})$$

So as $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ through a bit of rearranging I come to the answer that $Y\sim\gamma(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2},\frac{1}{2})$ correct me if I'm wrong!

So then since the MGF of a gamma function is:
$$\frac{\alpha^r}{(\alpha-t)^r}$$

By plugging the values in of $\alpha$ and $r$ I get:

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})^{1/2}}{(\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}-t)^{1/2}}$$

And this is the place that I am stuck at. Have I already arrived at the MGF of Y? And if I have how would I be able to define its domain?

Also if it is not too much trouble, can someone explain to me intuitively what is happening here it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is it $X=Y^2$ or $Y=X^2$? The first one contradicts the assumption of $X$ being Gaussian.

Comment: Oh Sorry! Let me edit it now!

Comment: Why don't you calculate the MGF directly? (i.e.,$\mathbb{E}[e^{tX^2}]$)

Comment: I wasn't able to since I couldn't factor out the $X^2$

Comment: Some day I'll start to suspect that people posting here don't go to LaTeX manuals on the web when they need help with that sort of thing.  I change $X$~$N(0,\sigma^2)$ to $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, entirely within the math-notation tags, rather than leaving the tilde outside those tags.  That makes the fonts match and provides proper spacing between characters.  It is standard usage.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[e^{tX^2}] & =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int _{-\infty}^\infty e^{\left(t-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\right)x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\\[10pt]
& =\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2}}, & 2\sigma^2 t<1 \\[6pt] \infty, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The mgf is $t\mapsto 1/\sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2}$, which is undefined when the thing under the radical is negative or zero.

So we need $1-2t\sigma^2>0$.  That means $t<\dfrac{1}{2\sigma^2}$.